# Decimals not rounding properly

Tags: c#

I am having an issue with rounding on a c# Payroll program.

I tested it with 15.50 hourly rate x 39.75 hours. This comes to $616.125 gross pay, rounded up to $616.13 gross.

Then I did a fixed Income tax of 25%, which means the final Net Pay of (15.50 x 39.75) x .25 = 462.10

However it keeps displaying a Net Pay of 462.09, so it must not be using the rounded gross pay for the display part. The Gross Pay and Income tax are displaying correctly

Here is all of the code, my guess is that this line needs to be changed among others:

```
decimal incomeTax = Math.Round(grossPay, 3) * taxRate;
```

Any ideas what I need to do to get it to round correctly?

```
decimal hourlyRate = 0;
decimal hoursWorked = 0;
decimal grossPay = 0m;
decimal incomeTax = 0m;
decimal netPay = 0m;

decimal taxRate = .25m;

private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal hourlyRate = Convert.ToDecimal(txtHourlyRate.Text);
    decimal hoursWorked = Convert.ToDecimal(txtHoursWorked.Text);
    decimal grossPay = Math.Round(hourlyRate * hoursWorked, 3);
    decimal incomeTax = Math.Round(grossPay, 3) * taxRate;
    decimal netPay = grossPay - incomeTax;

    txtGrossPay.Text = grossPay.ToString("c");
    txtIncomeTax.Text = incomeTax.ToString("c");
    txtNetPay.Text = netPay.ToString("c");
}

private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hourlyRate = 0;
    hoursWorked = 0;
    grossPay = 0m;
    incomeTax = 0m;
    netPay = 0m;

    txtHourlyRate.Text = "";
    txtHoursWorked.Text = "";
    txtGrossPay.Text = "";
    txtIncomeTax.Text = "";
    txtNetPay.Text = "";
}

private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: You should only be rounding at the very end of the calculation, not at each intermediate step.

Comment: But if I don't round Gross Pay during the multiplication then it wont figure correctly. I need them to be rounded correctly during the calculations

Answer (score 2):

`616.125` undergoes midpoint rounding. `decimal` uses banker's rounding by default. So (and this is something you can check yourself *very easily* if you just step through your code):

```
Math.Round(616.125M, 2) // 616.12M
```

Of course, you're also rounding to *three* decimal places, so you're actually getting `616.125M` instead of `616.12M` (or `616.13M`) anyway.

You're doing something quite dangerous - you're guessing around tax calculations. Don't do that. Find the applicable tax laws - they will have the exact method used for calculating taxes. Follow those *to a T*. They specify where and when and how you should round anything. Most likely, all rounding (except for the final price/tax) is supposed to be done to four decimal places, not two, but again, *don't guess* - read the laws, and make sure you understand them perfectly.

Comment: To "fix" it, use `Math.Round` and pass the correct `MidPointRounding` value. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am just making a test program, I know 25% is not everyone's tax rate. I am just trying to figure out how to show (15.50 x 39.75) x .25 = 462.10 instead of 462.09

Comment: @Programmer7 How does that have anything to do with my answer? I'm talking about the rules to calculate the tax, not about the tax rate. I also explained why you're getting your "anomalous" result - the rounding algorithm you're using in your head isn't the one you're using in your code.

Comment: What should I change it to so it makes it round the way it is supposed to? 
 
616.125 should round to 616.13

Comment: @Programmer7 If you're absolutely sure that 616.125 should round to 616.13, just use `Math.Round(..., ..., MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`. The reason banker's rounding is used by default is that this kind of rounding creates a noticeable statistical anomaly - basically, you round up a lot more often than you round down. Banker's rounding tends to make it even out better.

Answer (score 0):

`decimal grossPay = Math.Round(hourlyRate * hoursWorked, 3);`
returns `616.125`, for which the rest of the calculations correctly lead to `462.09....`.

It should be

`decimal grossPay = Math.Round(hourlyRate * hoursWorked, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`

Note the second parameter, the decimal place to round to, is 2 instead of 3, and the MidpointRounding parameter which will round `616.125` to `616.13` and get the result you expect.

Comment: As noted in my answer, `616.125M` actually rounds to `616.12`, not `616.13`.

Comment: 616.125 should round to 616.13 though

Comment: @Programmer7 You were rounding to 3 decimal places, which `616.125` falls within, so it didn't try to round further.

Comment: Thanks Harris, but when I try (22.5 * 39.75) * .25 it comes up with a Net Pay of 1 cent too much. It sounds like no one here knows the answer so I will ask elsewhere, thanks anyway